# How to get a intern variable from json response using jmeter's json path extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a problem, I get this json response from jmeter and I want to move tt_cid to param and then move it to another request.
I know how to get CID that is stand alone for example, but not hot to get the internal data after the '&'. (i want to get tt_cid param from the json 
this is under Nurl field[image]

I use json path extractor[image]

Comment: Please add text of response, you need the value after `tt_cid=`? you can use regular expression

Comment: What I provided is a PIC of the json response, and I highlighted the field that I want to move to a variable.

Comment: Can I use json path extractor? I am not familiar with regular expression, can somebody knows hot to parse this to a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `JSON Extractor` with similar expression to save the **full** nurl value in `nurl` variable name.

After it (post processor on same request) add `Regular Expression Extractor`, check radio button of `JMeter Variable` and put `nurl` variable name. inside use `tt_cid=(\w+)` to get the inner value:

```
Reference Name: tt_cid

Regular Expression: tt_cid=(\w+)

Template $1$

Match No. 1
```